# Activity Not found Exception Cant figureout the error

Tags: android, android-activity

Just started learning android app develpoment.
getting error "android.content.activitynotfoundexception no activity found"

Code:-
my Android Mainfest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.gtctest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>


        <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".StartingPointActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="com.GTC.STARTINGPOINTACTIVITY" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and my Splash Screen.java

```
package com.example.gtctest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle splashBundle) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(splashBundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        Thread timer=new Thread() {

            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    Intent openStartingPointActivityIntent=new Intent("com.GTC.STARTINGPOINTACTIVITY");
                    startActivity(openStartingPointActivityIntent);
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }

}
```

error:-

```
09-15 14:31:19.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1088): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-123
09-15 14:31:19.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1088): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.GTC.STARTINGPOINTACTIVITY }
09-15 14:31:19.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1088):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1512)
09-15 14:31:19.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1088):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1384)
09-15 14:31:19.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1088):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)
09-15 14:31:19.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1088):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3297)
09-15 14:31:19.587: E/AndroidRuntime(1088):     at com.example.gtctest.SplashScreen$1.run(SplashScreen.java:28)
```

Cant't figure out what is wrong.please help to solve this issue
And one more question
**In android mainfest the name action name can be anything or it has to be path from package like "*com.GTC.classname***"

Answer (score 0):

you have two application tags in your manifest. change it to one with both activities

Comment: Thanks a lot...
Can you please tell that action name can be anything or it should be path like packagename.classname??

Comment: I'm not that familiar with action name. I usually use `<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />` . maybe this link helps: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/action-element.html

Answer (score 0):

Create Intent Like Following...

```
Intent intentname =new Intent(SplashScreen.this,StartingPointActivity.class);
startActivity(intentname);
```

Change in your **AndroidManifest.xml** File..

You have defined two `<application>` tag....

remove that and change it to following..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.gtctest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- add new activities like this -->
        <activity
            android:name=".StartingPointActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <!-- if your activity in different package you can define like this... (xx.xxx is your package name define your package name there..) 
        <activity
            android:name="xx.xxx.StartingPointActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" > 
         -->

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: is it `STARTINGPOINTACTIVITY.class` or `StartingPointActivity.class` while creating `intent` for navigate 2 `StartingPointActivity`?

Comment: so please change that according to the class name in `manifest`

Answer (score 0):

please modify your manifest like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.gtctest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".StartingPointActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="com.GTC.STARTINGPOINTACTIVITY" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

ps: in android mainfest, the action name can be anything, but we used to make it like "com.xxx.intent.action.XXX".

Comment: @Sumeet it can be anything, but we used to make it like "com.xxx.intent.action.XXX"

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.gtctest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>


    <activity
        android:name=".StartingPointActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"/>

</manifest>

public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle splashBundle) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(splashBundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,StartingPointActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        },3000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```